# Dropwizard - Swagger UI not loading

Tags: swagger

I added the `dist` folder to my project, and, in index.html, changed the url to `localhost:9090/api-docs` where I can see my apis array. My question is "why isn't the swagger ui loading?"

Comment: Did you add dist folder in your AssetBundle?

Comment: Yes, I finally found a solution, it was using AssetsBundle [link](http://yobriefca.se/blog/2012/07/03/quick-and-dirty-super-ugly-starter-for-10-dropwizard/).

Comment: are you giving the right path of api-docs.json in index.php